# Getting **guruincsite** malware on my Magento site

Tags: magento-1.7, hosting

I got **guruincsite** virus with *https://www.magereport.com*: I deleted the virus from my database and now it shows there is no security risks. 
But when I access to my website browsers are blocking it "The site ahead contains malware".
this is my website *http://www.bijouterie-kuypers.com/*.
Is there any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Please discuss on hosting provider in order to  screen the systes,..

Answer (score 0):

I believe I'm right in saying that the warning will be removed automatically as long as the issue has been resolved.  The site probably got flagged while it was infected, but search engines have not caught up to that yet.  The next time the site is crawled it should be flagged clear, but you can speed up this process a bit by [submitting the site to Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) (and whatever other search engines you want to) which should in theory mean it's crawled sooner.